# Gremlin: how to find nodes that stem from starting node and have connection to a particular other node?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

[image]

For example using Appache modern graph starting at node person 1 (marko). I want to find all nodes that marko knows which have created software with name ripple. Meaning I want to find node 4.

What kind of query would I use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g.V(1).out('knows').where(out('created').has('name','ripple'))
```